# Set a specific color for a specific item in the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Currently i want to set a specific color for one of my item in the navigation drawer:

here is my code:

```
Menu menuNav= mNavigationView.getMenu();
                               MenuItem nav_item2 = menuNav.findItem(R.id.drawer_pay).setIconTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(
                                       mNavigationView.getContext(),
                                       R.color.background_gray));
```

but im receiving this kind of error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method setIconTintList(Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)Landroid/view/MenuItem; in class Landroid/view/MenuItem; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.MenuItem' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Way**

try using:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_pink"  //selected icon color
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_pink" //selected text color
app:itemBackground="@color/color_gray"
```

For your `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_pink"  
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_pink" 
app:itemBackground="@color/color_gray"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />
```

**Second Way**

For *programetically* change use:

```
navigationView.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList1);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList2);
```

Define `ColorStateList1` and `ColorStateList2` as:

For Navigation View Item Text Color

```
int[][] state = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

};

int[] color = new int[] {
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.WHITE
};

ColorStateList ColorStateList1 = new ColorStateList(state, color);
```

For Navigation View Item Icon Color

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

};

int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.WHITE
};

ColorStateList ColorStateList2 = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

Comment: This will change the color of all item in the navigation drawer, i need to be specific.